# coveragePathIgnorePatterns - ignore files with specific ending

Tags: jestjs, glob

Jest: I am trying to ignore all files that end with `.stories.tsx` for example `SomeFileName.stories.tsx`. Added in my `package.json` -> `*.stories.tsx` inside the `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` from `jest` like so:

```
"jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        ...
        "*.stories.tsx"
    ]
}
```

Unfortunately, running tests will throw the following error for **all** my tests:

> ● Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /*.stories.tsx/: Nothing to repeat
>     at String.match (<anonymous>)
>     ...
> ```

What do I need to add inside `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` to make this work?

Comment: If it is a regex, use `".*\.stories\.tsx$"` or `"<rootDir>/.*\.stories\.tsx$"`. Also, see [this reference](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragepathignorepatterns-arraystring).

Comment: It is a glob pattern, so you can just add the ! for not.

Comment: I need to read more about regex vs glob pattern. Still not getting why the error 'Invalid regular expression' shows up. @StevenScott as this is glob shouldn't it support: `*` for "anything"?

Comment: The directories are typically specified as 2 asterisks (**/) .  You do not need to escape the periods, they are expected.

Comment: @StevenScott according to jest [docs - coveragePathIgnorePatterns](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragepathignorepatterns-arraystring) it is an array of regexp pattern strings

Comment: I actually moved my configuration out of the package.json, and into its own JavaScript file. I find this easier, as I can change my test engine at any time in the package.json, and the external files for configuration make the commit to GIT easier, and then the logic for testing is self contained.  In the JavaScript configuration, it is a glob pattern.  If you are staying in package.json, does @WiktorStribiżew comment above not address your issue, as the periods, etc. need to be escaped for regex.

Comment: `"<rootDir>/.*\.stories\.tsx$"` inside package.json results in error: Invalid escape character in string.

Comment: Thank you, `<rootDir>/.*.stories.tsx$` in package.json actually did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on comments: solved by adding `"<rootDir>/.*.stories.tsx$"` in my `package.json`

```
"jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        ...
        "<rootDir>/.*.stories.tsx$"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I get an error for this

Comment: This solution works for me. I'm using Jest v27.

Answer (score 2):

I simply used this to ignore any files ending with d.ts

coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
".d.ts",
],

Comment: Upvoting this one because it's very simple and it seems to work well. As per the [`coveragePathIgnorePatterns` section in the "Configuring Jest" docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#coveragepathignorepatterns-arraystring) you should probably add a `"/node_modules/"` entry in the array as well; without this you may receive a Babel code generator deoptimization warning about large modules (file size > 500KB) causing your Jest tests to run a lot slower.

Answer (score 1):

I reference mine from javascript, to keep it out of my package.json, and in its own file, but either way, you can specify the patterns without escaping the periods in the file names.  Double asterisks are for paths.

```
"jest": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        ...
        "./**/*.stories.tsx",
        "./some_path/**/*.stories.tsx",
        "!./**/*.interface.tsx",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Added that but I am still getting the same error message mentioned in the question.

Comment: this property wants strings in regex not glob ('**' is a glob)